# How to scale an object in animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to create a scene for bridging in 3D-Printers. I scaled the abutments. But I couldn't find a way to scale bridge part. I know that my explanation is not that good. For you to better understand you can check the pics.

Thanks.

[image]

So my problem is,I don't know how to scale this part between 2 abutments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Bezier Curve and place it on top of your 2 cubes like in the picture

[image]

- Select the top-left corner adn press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude it and place the new vertex in the top-right corner (use <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to keep it at the same height). To get right corners set the *Properties > Object Data > Shape > Resolution Preview U* to 1.

[image]

- Keep extruding until you get a rectangular spiral (I did it quickly so it's not straight, but you get the point)

[image]

- Create a rectangle curve (it has to be a curve, not a mesh!) by using a circle with resolution set to 1 or by using the addon *Add Curve: Extra Objects* (it's already inBlender, you just need to enable it in the *User Preferences*).
  In the spiral's *Properties > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel > Object* insert your rectangle and enable *Fill Caps*

[image]

- Resize your rectangle and animate the *End* slider

If you want your corners to be a bit rounded you can increase your *Resolution Preview U*, but you'll have to play quite a bit with your vetex handles

Comment: But how can I animate this movement ? I'm sorry. I think my question wasn't clean :/

Just imagine like 3 printer extruder is printing this object. So after it prints abutments it's gonna print the bridge part.

My question is,how can I animate the printing bridge part ?

And thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wK2APNwEoSk basically I want to animate this :)

Comment: I have rewritten the answer